# Can Xcode copy the proper framework files in a workspace with several project dependencies?

Tags: xcode, frameworks, xcode-workspace

Here's the setup:

```
Workspace
| - Main Project
| - Framework Project 1
| - Framework Project 2
```

In order to get the main project to work on the simulator and debug/release device I have to add Frameworks 1 and 2 under Linked Frameworks and Libraries and then add a Copy Files Build Phase to which I then add the actual built Frameworks for the appropriate build by searching through the DerivedData folder. If I just add the Frameworks to Embedded Binaries it will copy the wrong Framework builds. For example, it will copy the simulator builds when trying to run on a device.